# Why 1.1-1 gives approx value but 1/10 gives 0.1 in python 3, when both of them represent the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> print(0.1)
0.1
>>> print(1/10)
0.1
>>> print(1.1 - 1)
0.10000000000000009
>>> print(1.1 % 1)
0.10000000000000009
>>> print(0.05 + 0.05)
0.1
```

When ideally all of them should output `0.10000000000000009` or something approximate to `0.1` as it cannot be represented precisely as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It all depends on how good those true values are represented in floating point. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken for a long and detailed explanation

Comment: yeah exactly, then why does print(0.1) in python prints the rational 0.1 in place of 0.10000000000000009

Comment: The problem is in representing `1.1` in binary floating point, check the decimal part `1.1%1`

Comment: i still dont get it, can you give some reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Check out the first link. The problem is that `1.1` can't has this precision in binary floating point `0.10000000000000009`. Hence adding or subtracting `1` to it, which *can* be well represented, will still result in this precision limitation

Comment: The link explains the binary floating point limitation, which I understand. But then, why does `print(0.1)` or `print(1/10)` gives the exact value instead of the precision limited value when internally, it cannot be represented precisely as it can be seen in `print(1.1-1)` or `print(1.1%1)`

Comment: all these should ideally output to 0.1 which can not be represented precisely, so 0.10000000000000009. But why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you print the exact actually represented values to see the differences:

```
>>> for s in '0.1', '1/10', '1.1', '1.1 - 1', '1.1 % 1', '0.05 + 0.05':
        print(s.rjust(11), ('=> %.70f' % eval(s)).rstrip('0'))

    
        0.1 => 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
       1/10 => 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
        1.1 => 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
    1.1 - 1 => 0.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
    1.1 % 1 => 0.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
0.05 + 0.05 => 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

As you see (and should expect), `1.1` has a larger absolute error than `0.1`. Subtracting `1` is exact, so the larger absolute error remains.